# How to Change CustomValidator ValidationGroup in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, vb.net-2010

If i have an asp control that has a particular Validation grop

```
  <asp:CustomValidator ID="myRequiredValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="myDropDown" ClientValidationFunction="myClientSideValidationFunction"  ValidateEmptyText="True" Display="None" ValidationGroup="group A"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

How can i change the group in javascript?

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">  
    function changeValidationGroup(validator) { validator.ValidationGroup("group B"); }
```

Or something like that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ASP.NET validation controls become `<span>` tags when rendered as HTML, simply change the validationGroup attribute of the required span to a new value:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title>Validation</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ChangeGroupName() {
            var groupName = $("#txtGroupName").val();
            if (groupName != '') {
                $("#validator").attr('validationGroup', groupName);
            }
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <input type="text" id="txtGroupName" />
    <asp:CustomValidator ID="validator" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Error" ValidationGroup="Group1"></asp:CustomValidator>
    <input type="button" value="OK" id="btnChangeGroup" onclick="ChangeGroupName()" />
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks that did it - i thought i tried it, but since its an ASP control i had to use $('#<%= idName.ClientID %>').attr('validationGroup', "my New Group");